# How to import a lot of datasets based on some patterns in R

Tags: r, csv, import

I have a lot of datasets (more than 20) to import and I want to import them all at the same time

The names of all of the datasets begin with: `SearchResults`, like:

```
SearchResults_2014_S1_2.csv
SearchResults_2014_S1.csv
SearchResults_2015_S1.csv
SearchResults_2015_S2.csv
```

All of the datasets have the same column names in the same order.

I want to import them all in a single code line then to bind them.

Comment: `data.table::rbindlist(lapply(list.files(...), data.table::fread(), ...), ...)` , `...` = function's arguments

Comment: Where do I indicate that only datasets whose name starts with ```SearchResults``` should be imported?

Comment: in the `pattern`-argument of the `list.files()`-function... see the help files of the functions mentioned in the comment above. hint: `pattern = "^Searchresults.*\\.csv$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to put together a whole example, since there is very scarce information here.

First step, is to have some data to load:

```r
library(tidyverse)

c("SearchResults_2014_S1_2.csv",
  "SearchResults_2014_S1.csv",
  "SearchResults_2015_S1.csv",
  "SearchResults_2015_S2.csv") %>% 
  walk(~
         iris %>% 
         sample_n(replace = TRUE,
                  size = nrow(iris) * 
                    # sample(c(2,3,4), size = 1)) %>%
                    runif(1, 1, 4)) %>%
         readr::write_excel_csv2(., file = fs::path(fs::path_temp(), .x)) %>% 
         print())
#'
fs::dir_ls(fs::path_temp())
```

And now the temporary directory has some valid data files, but
we want to make it a bit challenging, so let us save some other files
in the same directory:

```r
replicate(25,  fs::file_temp() %>% 
            write.csv(x = list()))
```

Then look at the files in the temporary directory once more:

```r
fs::dir_ls(fs::path_temp())
```

Finally, let us read the files that have `SearchResults` in the name:

```r
fs::dir_ls(
  path = tempdir(), 
  glob = "*SearchResults_*.csv",
  type = "file"
) %>% {
  tibble(path = ., 
            data = map(., . %>% 
                       read_csv2(show_col_types = FALSE))) 
} -> all_files
```

At this point, you've got the files in a `data`-variable. Run
`spec()` on them to see if the parsing went well in all of them.
Preferably set the `col_types` in the reading code above, so
you're sure that things are being read in correctly.

Finally, `unnest` to collate all the loaded datasets.
Plus a field called `path` that is only the filename, as to figure out
from whence the rows came from (in case there is another piece of information present in there).

```r
all_files %>% 
  mutate(path = fs::path_file(path)) %>% 
  unnest(data)
```

Comment: I took time to reply to the message cause I just hadn't got to the stage where I had to import all the databases whose names started with the same characters. This code is just a wonder @ Mossa